# Add multiple observers to this.listener to React component class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, events, listener

I want to add multiple observer functions to a React component. I use Firebase authentication and want to trigger actions

- when the user first signs in or out: [onauthstatechanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged)
- everytime the idToken changes: [onidtokenchanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged)

For this component I followed this [tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial#session-handling-with-firebasereact):

```
export class AuthContextProvider extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.state.firebase) {

      /** set listener whether user is signed in */
      this.listener = this.props.firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
        authUser => {
          if (authUser) {
            this.setState({ authUser });
          } else {
            this.setState({ authUser: null });
          }
        },
      );

      /**
       * ########
       * Question: Can I just add another function to this.listener?
       * Will both listeners trigger the appropriate times?
       * ########
       */
      this.listener = this.props.firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(
        authUser => {
          if (authUser) {
            // do something
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

It seemed to work in my implementation. Both events are triggered. But it seems wrong to me since I am reassigning `this.listener` when using `.onIdTokenChanged()`.

### How can I add both `onAuthStateChanged` AND `onIdTokenChanged` to `this.listener` correctly?

---

My question is also about `this.listener`. What exactly does it do? Where can I find documentation about it? Typing '"this.listener" react' shows many results about `window.addEventListener`. Is this an equivalent and achieves the same goal?

I assume `this` in `this.listener` refers to my class which extends `React.Component`. [The React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcomponent) does not mention anything about this listener property. Please correct me here if `this` refers to something else.

Comment: `this` is the component instance, but `listener` is unrelated to React; it's an arbitrary instance variable name. You won't find anything in React documentation about it because it's not specific to React. The second time you assign `this.listener =` you are writing to the same variable and losing the reference to the `onAuthStateChanged` handler.

Comment: @RossAllen Yes, that's what I was thinking. Would assigning the oberserver functions to two different arbitrary instance variable names like `this.listenerOnAuthStateChanged` and `this.listenerOnIdTokenChanged` solve my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ross Allen correctly pointed out in his comment:

> `this` is the component instance, but listener is unrelated to React; it's an arbitrary instance variable name. You won't find anything in React documentation about it because it's not specific to React. The second time you assign this.listener = you are writing to the same variable and losing the reference to the onAuthStateChanged handler.

The solution is to define two different arbitrary variables that are assigned to the component class:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.state.firebase) {

      // rename to onAuthStateChangedlistener 
      this.onAuthStateChangedlistener = this.props.firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
        authUser => {
          if (authUser) {
            this.setState({ authUser });
          } else {
            this.setState({ authUser: null });
          }
        },
      );

      // rename to onIdTokenChangedlistener 
      this.onIdTokenChangedlistener = this.props.firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(
        authUser => {
          if (authUser) {
            // do something
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

Now both listeners are active.